How to differentiate null and false in JMESPath?
From a JSON object, I want to return true if a key is missing, false otherwise.
How to achieve this?

First case, the key is defined:
And the value is false
{"my_key": false}

The expression my_key will return false.
And the value is a number:
{"my_key": 123}

The expression my_key will return 123.

Second case:
{"my_other_key": false}

The expression my_key would now return null.


I need an expression which would work with both cases, returning false (or other values) in the first case and true in the second one.
The built-in function not_null could be good, but, it treats false and null equally.

The expression you are looking for would uses a conditional "or" and can be expressed this way:
my_key == null || my_key

Simply put, it tells JMESPath to return either

the result of the test my_key == null, which would be true only if the value of my_key is strictly equal to null
or — so, if the test my_key == null result in a false — the value of my_key

Using it on:

the JSON object
{"my_key": false}

Would return false
the JSON object
{"my_key": 123}

Would return 123
the JSON object
{"my_other_key": false}

Would return true


Thanks, didn't realize == works here :)
